# Can we have more tag-based syntax highlighting options?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, syntax-highlighting

The dropdown available for moderators to set the syntax highlighting language for tags does not include all the [available language codes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). These are the options I see on Stack Overflow em Português:

> lang-bsh, lang-c, lang-cpp, lang-cs, lang-csh, lang-css, lang-hs, lang-html, lang-java, lang-js, lang-lisp, lang-lua, lang-ml, lang-perl, lang-php, lang-proto, lang-py, lang-rb, lang-scala, lang-sh, lang-sql, lang-vb, lang-xml, lang-vhdl

Pascal, R and Go, for example, are not included, but they're supported according to the linked meta post (and indeed work when used on inline overrides).

Could all the supported languages be included in the dropdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather not include all possible languages. It'd make the dropdown unwieldy for fairly little benefit since most of those will go unused. For many (most?) languages, picking "default" should remove the need for explicitly specifying *any* language since Prettify will just do the right thing anyway.

We also have a way to set a default language for all posts on the site, although that certainly makes no sense on a Stack Overflow.

Having said that, I added a few more options that look reasonably common/useful:

> lang-clj
>   lang-coffee
>   lang-go
>   lang-latex
>   lang-pascal
>   lang-r
>   lang-regex
>   lang-rust

These will be available in the dropdown starting with the next prod build.

Comment: Thanks, these extra options plus the default seem to suffice indeed.

Answer (score 2):

We're looking into this now, as a different subset is showing up on Portuguese, Japanese and the other languages we're working on which have not launched yet. They *should* be the same unless there's a compelling reason that they can't be, which I don't think exists, but will find out.